# invalid JSON generated by default Restsharp JSON serialiser

Tags: c#, restsharp

My code is below. When I post a JSON body that has `\v` in it, the server receives JSON that it cannot parse. Any help on how to make it work?

EDIT: well, the argument about my server not being able to parse it is weak, but http://jsonlint.com/ complains about it too. : )

in my emacs it looks like this:

```
{"key":"a^Kb"}
```

where `^K` I think is a single character.

code:

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient();
            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.Resource = "http://example.com/";

            var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data.Add("key", "a\vb");
            request.AddBody(data);

            var response = client.Execute<Dictionary<string, string>>(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it serialize it to? PostSharp makes `{"key":"a\u000bb"}`, which JSONLint accepts as valid.

Comment: BTW, I said "PostSharp" but I meant "Json.NET". I wasn't thinking, and RestSharp is entirely too close in name to PostSharp. Also, RestSharp sends the literal 0b (which is \v) byte over the wire. Maybe that's not interpreted correctly on the server.

Comment: I am using Ruby Sinatra and I read the body by `request.body.rewind` followed by `JSON.parse request.body.read`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default RestSharp JSON serializer serializes this as equivalent to the C# string `"{\"key\":\"a\vb\"}"`; that is, it sends the `\v` as a raw byte (`0b`) over the wire. This is why your server has trouble reading it. I'm unsure if this is legal JSON, but in any case there are ways to escape such a character to avoid issues.

I'd recommend using Json.NET to de/serialize your JSON. If you use the [the following class](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/86b31f9adf049d7fb821de8279154f41a17b36f7/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs) (originally part of RestSharp) as your serializer, it will use Json.NET and should work correctly, since it will encode the `\v` as `\u000b` over the wire. The code (sans comments, and renamed for clarity) is copied here for reference:

```
public class JsonNetSerializer : ISerializer
{
    private readonly Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer _serializer;

    public JsonNetSerializer()
    {
        ContentType = "application/json";
        _serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer
        {
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include
        };
    }

    public JsonNetSerializer(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ContentType = "application/json";
        _serializer = serializer;
    }

    public string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                jsonTextWriter.QuoteChar = '"';

                _serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, obj);

                var result = stringWriter.ToString();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    public string DateFormat { get; set; }
    public string RootElement { get; set; }
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

To use it, add this line:

```
request.JsonSerializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
```

And it will serialize like:

```
{
  "key": "a\u000bb"
}
```

Which is perfectly valid according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: This answer is correct, but beside implementing it, we could still come into trouble. When adding body of the Rest message we must provide real object and not object serialized as json string, since it will try to serialize json string as json, which raises the same error.